# Using the discord.js module outside of commands

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a discord bot. However, i am stuck on a part where i have to check every hour if a discord username is equal to the contents of an array. If it is, I have to make the bot remove a role. However, doing so would require using the discord.js module, which I don't know how to add into the code (I already have the bot set up in index.js).

I've tried to require `discord.js-commando` but it returns:

> "Error: A client must be specified"

This is the place of the problem:

```
class checkDet extends commando.Command {
```

This is where I want to use the `discord.js module`:

```
    var guild = bot.guilds.get("GUILD ID HERE"); 
    for (let [k, v] in Object.entries(guild.members)) {
    if (v.user.username == userName) 
    {                            
   v.removeRoles(v.roles).then(console.log).catch(console.error); 
    }
   }
```

Comment: Why do u want to use discord.js module if u are using commando

Comment: `v.roles.remove(v.roles).then(console.log).catch(console.error)` if you make it like that with roles.remove(...) it will work on commando

Comment: @Cursed I want to use the bot in a setInterval() loop outside of commands. Also, I found out that I coulda just pasted the whole thing in index.js. Thanks for the help anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple solutions. Solution 1: if you're just using Discord.JS and not the whole Commando module, try using `const Discord = require('discord.js');` at the top of that file and use
it as normal!

Another method would be to pass the whole commando module through. There's many ways to do it, however the easiest is probably to add `let commando;` at the top of the file, then create a `module.exports.define` function to set commando to the first argument. Then in the main bot file, run `require('path/to/my/command.js').define(commando);`.

Or even simpler, if all you need is a recursive check, why not put it in the main `bot.js` file, or even another file? Either invoke the file including the commando object, or just run a `setInterval` in the original file with the normal code.